# How to use all the parameters of the RaiseError function?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

The documentation for the RaiseError function shows that there can be up to 5 parameters

`RaiseError(S1,B1,S2,S3,B2)`

The example in the documentation shows parameters S1 and B1. I am looking for an example of using the other parameters, S2, S3 and B2. We want to get as much information when an error occurs as possible and would like to be able to write that information to a data extension.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Yay for descriptive parameter names!

Answer (score 2):

[The documentation](https://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/api_ampscript_functions/) states:

---

### RaiseError(S1,B1,S2,S3,B2)

#### Arguments

- S1    The error message to be displayed
- B1    Optional - a value of true stops the send for the current subscriber only
- S2    Optional - displays API Error Code
- S3    Optional - displays API Error Number
- B2    Optional - records information written to data extension before the error occurs. A value of 1 retains information written to data extensions before the error occurs, even if the subscriber is skipped.

---

S2 and S3 are error code strings. I have zero familiarity with AMPScript, but I'm guessing that the errors are related to the output from other functions. Elsewhere, there's a line of code that reads:

```
RaiseError(@ts_statusMsg, 0, @ts_statusCode, @errorCode)
```

Where @ts_StatusCode is the result of a function call (InvokeCreate), and @errorCode is an out parameter from the same function call.

B2 allows some of the data to survive from a call, even though the subscriber themselves are skipped. The data from the following calls will still affect the subscriber:

---

- InsertDE
- InsertData
- UpdateDE
- UpdateData
- UpsertDE
- UpsertData
- DeleteDE
- DeleteData

---

Passing a value of false in B2 reverts all of the changes that would have been made.